# Time taken or taken time?

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives

If I have a transmitter that sends one packet in time T, which of the following sentences are correct and **why**? Please let me know if there a grammar rule for this.

1. T  is the **taken time** by the Transmitter to send one packet.
2. T  is the **time taken** by the Transmitter to send one packet.
3. The Transmitter's **taken time** is T.
4. The **taken time** of the Transmitter is T.

Comment: You need "time taken" for all of these.  I'm not sure how to back that up, though, so I'll give you a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that "time taken" is correct in sentences #1 and #2 is because "taken" is part of the phrase "taken by the Transmitter", which should not be broken up by the word "time":

> T is the time **taken by the Transmitter**...

For sentences #3 and #4, the word "taken" is in the passive voice, and the proper way to express the subject is by saying "taken by the Transmitter". Referencing the subject in other ways comes across as awkward and unnatural. The best way to write this sentence would be:

> The **time taken by the Transmitter** is T.